How should I transfer continually updating Google Cloud Storage with parquet files to BigQuery?
I have a Cloud Storage bucket that has an event-driven Storage Transfer from S3. The files are in parquet format. I want to load all files (previous and incoming) to BigQuery. How should I do this?

The solution is BigLake. But, I never used it, because I do not have AWS account.... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/biglake-intro

As Mentioned by the @guillaume blaquiere  solution for this  is BigLake. For more details refer to this documentation. And also you can load all the parquet files from cloud storage to BigQuery. Check in this link to load parquet files.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.
Feel free to edit this answer for additional information
